# Getting Overflow in constant value computation

Tags: c#-4.0

The following code:

```
private const uint FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS = 0x00001800;

public void someFunc(){
    byte[] command = new byte[16];


    command[11] = (byte)(FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS >> 24);
    command[10] = (byte)(FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS >> 16);
    command[9] = (byte)(FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS >> 8);
    command[8] = (byte)(FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS); //error: Overflow in constant value computation
}
```

throws an error `Overflow in constant value computation`.

Why? From what I understand `0x00001800` <= `0xffffffff` so there should be no overflow happening.

And why don't the other 3 lines throw an error? I tried to do:

```
command[8] = (byte)(FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS >>0);
```

thinking that the right shift operator was somehow checking for the overflow condition but this still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because the value you are trying to cast to a `byte` cannot be represented by a byte.

A `byte`'s [max value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is `0x000000FF` (or 255). But you are trying to cast `0x00001800` (or 6144). A byte simply cannot contain that value.

The remaining works fine since, after the bit shift, the value is small enough to be represented by a byte

```
FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS >> 24 = 0
FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS >> 16 = 0
FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS >> 8  = 24
```

It seems like you are thinking about an unsigned integer's [max value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), which is `0xFFFFFFFF` (or 4294967295)

Comment: Thanks! So how would I go about programatically getting the last 8 bits of my constant value?

Comment: Doh! Use the binary AND operator with `0xFF`!! Thanks again!

Comment: You found the answer before I could write my comment. :) You're welcome.